# How to increase MATLAB memory limitation in ubuntu? (how to use mkswap, swapon for MATLAB?)

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, out-of-memory

I am currently suffer from 'Out of Memory' problem in MATLAB. (in Ubuntu 12.04 environment)

I increased physical memory of my machine by 16GB(4GB*4) to 32GB(4GB*8), and monitoring memory usage of MATLAB by command 'top', but it increase with same speed, and reach at same maximum point. And then 'Out of Memory' message comes out.

I think there is memory limitation in MATLAB application, but I don't know how to increase it.

Mathworks document saids that I can try **'mkswap'**, and **'swapon'** command. But I don't know how to use it for MATLAB.  (http://www.mathworks.co.kr/kr/help/matlab/matlab_prog/resolving-out-of-memory-errors.html)

Anyone knows how to use **'mkswap'**, and **'swapon'** ?

Comment: Please, see the thread about the issue http://askubuntu.com/q/799834/25388

Answer (score 0):

To utilize >4GB of RAM, you need a 64bit OS and a 64bit version of Matlab.

- what is the output of computer('arch')? You can check this from help->about
- what does the output of 'memory' show?
- in a terminal windows, what does uname -m output?

Matlab *should* be able to consume all of the available RAM, so unless you are allocating more memory than physically avaialble it should just work on a x64 machine running x64 Matlab.